# Login into Intacct with CasperJS to scrape

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

can someone point me to the an example to make a CasperJS/PhantomJS script that logs in into Intacct and renders a screen cap.

```
casper = require("casper").create({
    waitTimeout: 60000,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    },
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
         loadImages:  false,
         loadPlugins: false,
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)'
    }
});

casper.start("https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml");

casper.then(function() {
    casper.fill('form[name="iamain"]', {
        '.company': 'company',
        '.login': 'username',
        '.passwd': 'password',
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture("screen.png");
});

casper.run();
```

** UPDATED THE CODE FROM THE SUGGESTION BELOW

The image that it saves is just the same login screen.

This is what shows in the cmd screen (UPDATED):

```
Warning PhantomJS v2.0 not yet released. There will not be any official support for any bugs until stable version is released!
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 4 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/logincontent/product/index.html, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/logincontent/marketing/index.html, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml?.topper=%2Fia%2Facct%2Flogin.phtml, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1071821189/?random=1427724789483&cv=7&fst=1427724789483&num=1&fmt=1&label=2QNMCIiK0AMQheOK_wM&guid=ON&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1040&u_aw=1920&u_cd=32&u_his=1&u_tz=-240&u_java=false&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&frm=1&url=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml&ref=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml&vis=1, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.com/ads/user-lists/1071821189/?label=2QNMCIiK0AMQheOK_wM&fmt=1&num=1&cv=7&frm=1&url=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml&ref=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml&random=2994291944, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[debug] [phantom] start page is loaded
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/4 https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml (HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="iamain"]'
[debug] [remote] Set ".company" field value to company
[debug] [remote] Set ".login" field value to username
[debug] [remote] Set ".passwd" field value to ************
[info] [remote] submitting form to login.phtml?.done=frameset.phtml, HTTP POST
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/4: done in 1889ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/4 https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/Phantom Test/screen.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/Phantom Test/screen.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/4: done in 2073ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml?.done=frameset.phtml, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml?.done=frameset.phtml"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/logincontent/product/index.html, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/logincontent/marketing/index.html, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml?.topper=%2Fia%2Facct%2Flogin.phtml%3F.done%3Dframeset.phtml, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1071821189/?random=1427724790656&cv=7&fst=1427724790656&num=1&fmt=1&label=2QNMCIiK0AMQheOK_wM&guid=ON&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1040&u_aw=1920&u_cd=32&u_his=2&u_tz=-240&u_java=false&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&frm=1&url=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml%3F.done%3Dframeset.phtml&ref=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml%3F.done%3Dframeset.phtml&vis=1, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.com/ads/user-lists/1071821189/?label=2QNMCIiK0AMQheOK_wM&fmt=1&num=1&cv=7&frm=1&url=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml%3F.done%3Dframeset.phtml&ref=https%3A//www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml%3F.done%3Dframeset.phtml&random=3619079888, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Done 4 steps in 2821ms
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the site hasn't loaded yet and won't show the logged in page. Try adding your `casper.capture("screen.png");` inside another `casper.then()` block, this will make casper capture the screenshot after it received the response for the request that got triggered by your actions. May be there is a better way to do it but this has worked for me in several occasions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated the code with your suggestion and I pasted the results - the capture is still of the login page and not the "dashboard" page.